# How to amplify a signal containing square pulses at milivolts to a couple volts

Tags: amplifier, digital-communications, instrumentation-amplifier

I was on it for a time. I'm planning to generate a signal containing square pulses from a smart phone's audio output. As I can get any shape of audio signal from smartphone's audio output, I want to encode digital data into audio signal with square pulses.(Surely pulses represent 1.)

I wrote an application and generated desired signal, everything is OK so far. But I measured peak value of pulses, it's approximately 20 mV. The problem is: this needs to be amplified to a couple volts such as 3 V so that digital devices can read the data properly.

One solution was using transistors, but I couldn't find any kind of transistor having such low threshold voltage.

Transformers also won't work because data is rare and very little part of the whole signal.

I couldn't come up with another solution.
Please help me, what is the simplest way to get this?

EDIT:
OpAmp's will help, I guess. Thank you

Comment: Surely the audio output of your phone can put out more than 20 mV!

Comment: Have you looked at Op Amps?

Comment: How were you measuring the output voltage?  Did you have it connected to anything else?  What frequency was the output?  Maybe the phone has an ac-coupling capacitor that is blocking low frequencies.

Comment: In software I put full digital amplitude value(32767 for 16-bit pcm) into the array, which will be converted to audio. I plugged a jack connector into my phone, connected jack pins to ossiloscope probe. I was surprised too, but it was 20 mV. I will check again when I get a chance. Frequency of pulses were 500 Hz by the way.

Comment: Use a voltage comparator.

Comment: Yes use a comparator. If the audio gets processed (for example compressed) it may be changed. Maybe your PCM data stream was passed through some additional processing routines. It may be advisable to use some other data encoding method. I wonder of FSK would work better? Not my area. Sorry.